# Woocommerce validate with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using `add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );` to set my own field with NIP (Polish Company Number). I added a regex pattern to this input but I also have to validate this number using jQuery while submitting.

I wrote a jQuery function, which works fine when I use it in another form (in edit my account view) but woocommerce is ignoring it while ordering product in shop.

Why would a woocommerce ignore my script in order process?
Below jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#billing_nip").closest( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        var nip = $("#billing_nip").val(); 
    if(!nip){
        return false;
    } else {
        var verificator_nip = new Array(6,5,7,2,3,4,5,6,7); 
        //var nip = nipNumber.replace(/[\ \-]/gi, '');
        if (nip.length != 10)  { 
            return false;
        } else  {
                var n = 0;
                for (var i=0; i<9; i++) {
                    n += nip[i] * verificator_nip[i]; 
                }
                n %= 11;
                if (n != nip[9]) { 
                    alert("Sprawdź liczby w numerze NIP ") 
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } 
        }
    return true;
    });
});
```